# Why does Stack Overflow give a badge for "Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, badges, disciplined-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the purpose of the “disciplined” badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7609/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-disciplined-badge)

Isn't it a bad thing?

Comment: See: [What is the purpose of the "disciplined" badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7609/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-disciplined-badge)

Comment: By post does it intend a question or an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the badge is less than ideal, but the purpose it rewards is important - removing bad posts is a good thing for site maintenance and cleanliness. Sometimes you can edit a poor/dangerous/off-topic answer into a good one, but sometimes it really isn't salvageable. Deleting, then removes it from general public view, and by extension brings better attention to all of the good content.

Comment: So yes, it's a bad thing that the bad answer got 3 upvotes...

Comment: @Wooble, sometimes it's a good post that you delete, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: By post does it intend a question or an answer?